# Is it even possible to know, from the outside, whether a physical system is conscious?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, knowledge, mind-body

I take it for granted that other humans, and other higher animals like chimpanzees and dogs and cats, are conscious. But is it even possible to know, from the outside, whether a physical system is conscious? Not merely that it is likely that they are conscious, but to be certain that they are? Of course, this gets to the question of whether it is possible to know anything for certain. Personally, I think one can never be certain whether anyone or anything else is conscious, but what have philosophers written about this?

Comment: If physicalism is true, and most philosophers think it is, then at least in principle it is possible - but the gap between "in principle" and "in practice" is huge, possibly a gap humanity will never cross in this case

Comment: I do not know if it helps but one philosophy that comes to mind that may interest you is: Conscious Realism, it is a philosophy in psychology regarding the conscious and the non-conscious and its interaction with 'the objective world'. Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible to know, from the outside, that the world is not a hallucination? The answer is yes on appropriate standard of "knowing", which is not absolute certainty or anything of that sort. It is no different with consciousness. The reason you think humans, chimpanzees, dogs and cats are conscious is that they behave that way and have the biological equipment that supports consciousness in humans like you (brain, etc.). And that is knowing enough. Of course, that knowledge can be and is strengthened by neuroscience as it establishes more precise neural correlates of conscious behaviors.